# A pointerless node in c++

Tags: pointers, nodes

How could you make a pointerless node. A node that does not contain pointers.

This would be user for a linkedlist or something

Also how can you insert into a pointerless node.

The other parts can have pointers. Just the node cannot.

Comment: If you keep your nodes in an array, you can use indexes into the array instead of pointers

Comment: What's the point of having a linkedlist with pointless nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague.  A linked list uses pointers by definition.  So pointerless nodes cannot exist and would be pointless.  You could split out the pointer stuff from the rest of the payload so that the pointer structure contains pointers to previous, next and payload; is that what you mean?  Like this:

```
struct payload
{
    // data defs but no pointers
};

struct node
{
    struct node *next, *prev;
    struct payload *payload;
};
```